# Webpack "Not a function" error for calling a class in React

Tags: reactjs, es6-class

In a react app, I have some business logic I'm trying to encapsulate in class called Authentication.  When I try to call a method called configure on the Authentication class I get the following error:

> TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__authentication_js**.a.configure is not a function

In my React app.js file I import the authentication class with:

```
import Authentication from './authentication.js';
```

and then I try to access it inside my constructor as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    Authentication.configure();
}
```

The code for authentication.js is as follows:

```
class Authentication {

  constructor(props) {
    console.log('inside constructor of Authentication class');    
  }

  configure(){
    //some setup logic, still fails if I comment it all out
  }
}
export default Authentication;
```

I'm unsure how exactly to troubleshoot this issue.  I know I've seen similar issues in react before where an internal method has not had the bind method called against it, but I'm unsure if that is needed for a public method of an external class and if it is required, I'm not sure how to implement it.  Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`configure` is an instance method of the `Authentication` class.

Either make `configure` **static**, or export an **instance** of `Authentication`.

Comment: Thank you!  I was over complicating this in my mind.

Comment: Wow, same error, same flow (I've written an auth helper class). Thanks for the answer!